# Directory of Mining Hardware Companies

Tags: mining-hardware

Are there any well-curated directories of Bitcoin mining hardware manufacturers?

Answer (score 2):

The current king of the hill is BitMain and their AntMiner S9. They provide 14 Th/s, but it's sold out at the moment.

Unfortunately, the industry changes so fast that it's hard to have anything current. Companies go bankrupt, new manufacturers appear out of nowhere and it's hard to keep up. The best directory of manufacturers and their wares is here:

https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Mining_hardware_comparison

Comment: I'm familiar with the wiki. I asked because it seems almost every mining hardware manufacturer has gone out of business. If that's the case it's a cause of grave concern. I hope I'm mistaken.

Comment: It's a good chance that there are other "private" manufacturers who don't sell to the public, but make their own custom devices to run in their own mining farms.  You might not ever find out who they are.